# BaseLoaderCallback: OpenCV Manager package was not found! How to install and why necessary?

Tags: android, opencv

I have trouble with the `BaseLoaderCallback`.

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {;
    super.onResume();
    // mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
}
```

When I run the app, I get a dialog that says

> OpenCV Manager package was not found! Try to install it?

When I click `yes`, it opens the Play Store but it can't be found.

What is this package? How do I get it and why do I need it? When I run `mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();` directly from `onResume` it works anyways, is there a risk not using the manager?

Comment: Jonas has you solved this problem? enableView() in onResume method can't help because the camera on my device doesn't show anything.